# Сложное или простое предложение?

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

> То был не весёлый, смеющийся трепет весны, не мягкое шушуканье, не долгий говор лета, не робкое и холодное лепетание поздней осени, а едва слышная дремотная болтовня.

Это предложение является сложным или простым?

Answer (score 2):

Упростим:  *То был не А, а Б.* Теперь видно, что это простое предложение?

Это схематически. А в реальном предложении нарушено правило:

> Если однородные члены имеют общий главный член, необходимо учитывать, что каждый из однородных членов должен быть лексически и грамматически соотнесён с этим общим главным членом ([3.4. Предложения с однородными членами](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/784-34_predlozheniya_s_odnorodnymi_chlenami.html))

Сказуемое *был* стоит в мужском роде, а дополнения *лепетание* и *болтовня* — в женском.

Comment: Упростим: _То **был <...> болтовня**._ (???)

Comment: @slava1947  Значит, это простое ошибочное предложение  :))

Comment: @slava1947 Я не уверен, что верно понимаю синтаксис этого предложения (где подлежащее, где сказуемое). Помогите.

Comment: @М_Г  Всё у Вас верно.

Comment: @Ксения, Спасибо!

Comment: Ксения: М_Г Всё у Вас верно. === Я лучше промолчу...

Comment: @slava1947 Не молчите, истина дороже.

Answer (score 2):

Это простое осложнённое предложение. Подлежащее — ТО, сказуемое — был не трепет, не шуршание, не говор, не лепетание, болтовня.

Answer (score 0):

*То был не весёлый, смеющийся трепет весны, не мягкое шушуканье, не долгий говор лета, не робкое и холодное лепетание поздней осени, а едва слышная дремотная болтовня.*

Как уже было сказано, условная схема этого предложения такова:  **то был не А, а Б.** Это простое предложение,  осложненное однородными сказуемыми: ***был*** – связка, а именную часть составляет **однородный ряд** существительных. Таких примеров много в Нацкорпусе.

Согласование в числе и роде **формальное**, по ближайшему сказуемому.

**У Розенталя:** http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm §189. Согласование связки с именной частью сказуемого. Пример: при подлежащем, выраженном местоимением **это**, например: Я случайно посмотрел на эту книгу; ***это*** была хрестоматия... (Гл. Успенский).

В нашем случае использовано местоимение ***то***.

Примеры:

В первую секунду я испытал нечто похожее на мгновенный страх, **но то был не страх**, а бессознательное, самозащитное **отталкивание** от себя чего-то ненужного и неясного, с чем я не мог согласиться. [Ю. В. Трифонов. Нетерпение (1973)]

То был **не сон и не бдение**. [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Неоконченное. Благонамеренные речи (1872-1876)]

То был **не человеческий голос, не рожок, не гусли, а что-то похожее** на шум ветра в тростнике, если бы тростник мог звенеть, как стекло или струны. [А. К. Толстой. Князь Серебряный (1861-1863)]